# Office XML link no longer working

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use the relatively simple XML code in an Access database to disable the options button in the file menu. However, when I try to visit the website the xml references, the website shows up as not currently available. Anyone know a new reference website or a way around this? Code I'm using as a reference in the system table USysRibbons:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
     <ribbon startFromScratch="true" />
</customUI>

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
     <ribbon startFromScratch="false"></ribbon>
          <backstage>
               <button idMSO="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
          </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Comment: See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace  ... "the namespace specification does not require nor suggest that the namespace URI be used to retrieve information; it is simply treated by an XML parser as a string."

Comment: Ah I see. I understood it to mean that the XML was picking up all of the background XML code from the link, and then my code modified part of this code to remove the options button. This code still isn't working however, any idea what needs to be changed to make it work?

Comment: Sorry - not familiar with RibbonXML

Comment: This is now resolved. I found the error in the XML after pouring through some of the background XML code reference files. Note that Access XML seems to be very picky about capital letters and syntax. The correct code is: <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
          <ribbon startFromScratch="true" />
          <backstage>
               <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
          </backstage>
</customUI>